How do I boot, in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, when problem persists after using recommended Boot repair?
Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on an iMac16,2 (from 2015), I started having problems booting. A dark screen would show a blinking cursor.
Please see these two images of the screen (via tty) for system info:


Eventually I tried using the recommended boot repair (from a live USB).
Please use this pastebin link for the Boot repair report:
https://pastebin.com/gdkhpup7
The problem is still there. See these 4 images of a dmesg printout.
sudo dmesg —level=err,warn
Colouring of priority is lost in ‘less’: is there a better way of sharing this information, given that I am accessing it via tty only?




I’m a sporadic user and do not understand what to do next, if you can please advise.
Update:
I can boot into a grub, GNU GRUB version 2.06. For BASH-like text.
I can get into tty. But to get into the GUI from there, using startx has not worked.
Sometimes, when booting, I get a menu offering Advanced Options and then recovery mode. When I last tried that it led to a repeating line:
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 120: /lib/recovery-mode/options/whiptail: No such file or directory
Resolution
Without being able to use apt update via tty, I decided to reinstall the system entirely. Full apt upgrade was part of that process and the problem has been solved this way.
As reinstall is a last resort it doesn't feel like an answer as such. I don't know if I had been more confident with the command line I could have avoided a reinstall by changing to root from a live USB?
The new system still flags up a warning about the ACPI and BIOS, if there is information there that would help identify an underlying issue. Please see this pastebin post:
https://pastebin.com/XpcHtXaY
I am working from a very basic understanding (/misunderstanding)! Thank you for your help!

What does work? Do you get into grub? Can you boot into the tty but fail to start the display server/graphical environment?

Yes, I can get into grub, GNU GRUB version 2.06.  I can also get into tty: from there I have just tried to get into the GUI with the command ‘startx’ which did not work.

I don't think this situation is usually considered boot failure. Im not sure running startx makes sense because ubuntu normally starts the display server with gdm3 as root (so you can log in using a graphical interface). Your machine might use wayland as the display server in stead of Xorg (not sure what the default is nowadays). I suggest running the following things as root

apt update
apt upgrade
systemctl enable gdm3
systemctl start gdm3

and see where that takes you
if the gdm3 service fails to start, maybe systemd will have more info as to why. You might try something like

journalctl -u gdm3

When researching the issue on your own, you should probably use gdm3 as part of your google search query.

Thank you, @Fictional. I was not even able to run apt update, so decided to reinstall the system.Then apt upgrade also functioned. It is now working OK, allowing me to use the GUI. I do still notice a warning about the ACPI, which I will post in an update to my original question.

Odd for apt to not work if you manage to get into the tty. Its usually one of the last things to break for me. Reinstalling is always an option, but potentially a hassle. Happy you got it working. Not sure what ACPI warning you are getting, but from experience it could be a minor firmware bug (especially on older uefi), which you might ignore.
